# Vulnerability scanners for .efi files

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, desktop

I have an .efi file with some hardware diagnostic tool like Memtest and I need to provide a security assessment for it. I am wondering, if there are any automated scanners, that can scan .efi files for vulnerabilities, like Black Duck? I've discovered chipsec framework, but I've not found any options to scan standalone .efi file.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Why? Memtest doesn't have any external interfaces except the keyboard interface. Who cares if it has a buffer overflow?